# NSDateFormatter dateFromString for 24hr date gives wrong time

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I want to add event to native calender.I am having problem in getting date accurate time  from string. I have set locale,24 hr format. but still getting the same bug.

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];

   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

  NSLocale *locale =[[[NSLocalealloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]autorelease];  

  [dateFormatter setLocale:locale];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];


  event.startDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10/02/2011 15:39"];
```

And event.startDate is getting set as : 2011-02-10 10:09:00 GMT

Can anyone help???

Comment: What is the value of lblStartDate.text?

Comment: lblStartDate.text is:-10/02/2011 12:12 PM

Answer (score 0):

I think your event.startDate is re initializing,

Its showing the current time, i think so.

Check whether any code there like

```
event.startDate=[NSDate date];
```

**EDIT:**

how you checking your event.startDate vale? If it is by using NSLog check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966251/getting-nsdate-from-nsstring).

Comment: its giving 2011-02-10 07:19:21 GMT bt correct time is 2011-02-10 12:51:21 GMT

Comment: my problem is with time being returned

Comment: May i know where are you from? Its showing the time GMT-5:30. Are you from that time zone?

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,
>
> I tried with setting timezone as GMT and it worked properly. Please
>   add the below code and it should work.

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```